# How to use Ubuntu 19.10's integrated DLNA server without GUI?

Tags: server, 19.10, dlna, minidlna

I have a NAS running Ubuntu Server 18.04 with minidlna. Minidlna has been unmaintained for a long time and now it kind of sucks. I read that 19.10 has an integrated dlna server, but I couldn't find any instructions on how to use it on Ubuntu Server without a GUI. I'm willing to upgrade to a non-LTS version if it gives me a better DLNA experience, but I'd like now if and how it's possible to use that feature without a GUI.

Comment: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/10/ubuntu-dlna-media-sharing-server and https://tipsonubuntu.com/2019/11/17/turn-ubuntu-19-10-dlna-media-server/ may be helpful; they illustrate how to enable sharing from 19.10 Desktop. https://askubuntu.com/a/1181476/197910 shows the difference between Desktop and Servicer is small.

Comment: I read that, but the instructions are only for use with a GUI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 19.10: How to share media to your TV, games consoles, etc without installing a third-party client?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185239/ubuntu-19-10-how-to-share-media-to-your-tv-games-consoles-etc-without-install)

Comment: @K7AAY No, because they're still using a GUI...

Comment: No, again, these instructions are only for GUI use. My question is, how can I do that via the terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DLNA server in question is [Rygel](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Rygel), which is part of Gnome, which Ubuntu uses. Normally that might suggest you might need Gnome (and a graphical server), but you can —as far as I can see— run this headless, from a command line.

```
sudo apt install rygel  # double-check what this is going to install before saying yes!
```

Then edit `/etc/rygel.conf` or `~/.config/rygel.conf` based on `man rygel.conf` to set your settings. The main one you'll want is the `uris` setting, to define where your media is stored.

```
uris=/data/my-films;/data/tv-recordings
```

Then just run `rygel`. You'd probably test it at this point before adding a systemd service to keep it alive.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. I checked it and it doesn't install a graphical server. I'll try it out.

Comment: I have to wait for it to process my huge library. It's also present in the 18.04 repositories, so I don't have to use a non-LTS version on my server which makes me happy. Only thing is I'll need to manually add it as a service.